# website header clickible only when browser window is not maximized

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am having problems a website that I am working on. The header is only clickible when the browser window is not maximized. I have tested this with windows 7 and ubuntu, in both Chrome and FF. I really don't know where to look to fix this issue, any advice would be appreciated!

My goal is to make the header link back to the main "home" page which seems to work when the browser window is not fully expanded, but when the browser window is maximized, it doesn't work.

I am using WP 3.8.1 and I have made a child theme of the fairly popular "customizr" theme.

Thanks!

EDIT: website link removed after problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is that `.navbar-wrapper` gets a relative position and `z-index:200` after the resize. I didn't verify the scripts, but I'm assuming this is for responsiveness.

So now, `.navbar-wrapper` which is the last rendered element and is relatively positioned, gets the same z-index as your title, and part of it's box is covering the title link.

You should set a higher z-index on `.brand`, and make it relatively positioned (otherwise it won't have any effects on `.navbar-wrapper`), or you can change the rendering order and keep the existing z-indexes (although you'd probably still have to make it relatively positioned).

---

**/edit:** the quickest fix is to add this in one of the stylesheets:

```
  .tc-header .brand { position:relative; z-index:201 }
```

Comment: This is a little above my head in terms of website coding, but sounds promising. I read into this and see what I can find out. Any hints would be appreciated. One thing that may be of note is that I have a style.css in my  child theme that contains the following line for styling: 
'.navbar-inner{display:none;}'

Comment: That seemed to work perfectly. I added that to my child theme's style.css and it's set! Can you explain what this actually does, for my knowledge, as well as any one else who may stumble across this?

Comment: I just explained in the post. `position:relative` makes sure that it can be reordered with other relatively positioned siblings (within the same parent), and `z-index:201` is a higher index that 200 making sure it's rendered on top of other siblings, which makes it clickable again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

`.clearfix:after { clear: both; }` and it will work correctly.

Comment: Which file is that in? and if it works, can I add that to my child theme's function.php to allow updates to the theme without breaking my site?

Comment: Well, it says blue.css to me, but I do not have insight in your files or structure, so that you have to solve by yourself. And yes, of course you can to that...

Comment: I tried commenting this out with /* */ and it didn't seem to make a difference :(